# Not getting correct output from parser

Tags: python, parsing, compiler-construction

In all essence, I'm new at this.  I am building a code for my parser.  I have been debugging for over an hour with this code and I can not get the correct output.  The "List index out of range" message is showing on my output.  The code is shown below.  Any feedback or helo would be appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

```
import sys

#  LL(1) Parser code
if __name__ == '__main__':

    myStack = []  # stack created
    terminals = ['WHILE', 'num', 'id', 'SUB', 'COMPARE', 
'ADD', 'RP', 'LP', 'ASGN', 'DO', 'IF', 'SC']

    # scanner output
    output = ['id', 'ASGN', 'num', 'SC', 'WHILE', 'LP', 'id', 
'COMPARE', 'num', 'RP', 'id', 'ASGN',
              'id', 'ADD', 'id', 'SC', '$']

    count = 0

    # Parse Table
    parseTable = {('<program>', 'id'): ['<statement_list>'], ('<program>', 'SC'): ['<statement_list>'],
                  ('<program>', 'WHILE'): ['<statement_list>'], 
('<program>', `'DO'): ['<statement_list>'],
                  ('<program>', 'IF'): ['<statement_list>'],


('<program>', '$'): ['<statement_list>'],
                  ('<statement_list>', 'id'): 
['<statement>', 'SC', '<statement_list>'],

                  ('<statement_list>', 'SC'): 
['<statement>', 'SC', '<statement_list>'],
                  ('<statement_list>', 'WHILE'): 
['<statement>', 'SC', '<statement_list>'],
                  ('<statement_list>', 'DO'): 
['<statement>', 'SC', '<statement_list>'],
                  ('<statement_list>', 'IF'): 
['<statement>', 'SC', '<statement_list>'],
                  ('<statement_list>', '$'): 
['E'],
                  ('<statement>', 'id'):


['id', 'ASGN', '<expr>'],
                  ('<statement>', 'SC'): ['SC'],
                  ('<statement>', 'WHILE'): 
['WHILE', '<paren_expr>', '<statement>'],
                  ('<statement>', 'DO'): 
['DO', '<statement>', 'WHILE', '<paren_expr>'],


                 ('<statement>', 'IF'): 
['IF', '<paren_expr>', '<statement>'],
                  ('<paren_expr>', 'LP'): 
['LP', '<expr>', 'RP'],

                  ('<expr>', 'num'): ['<test>'], 
('<expr>', 'id'): ['<test>'], ('<expr>', 'LP'): ['<test>'],
                  ('<test>', 'num'): ['<sum>', '<test_opt>'], 
('<test>', 'id'): ['<sum>', '<test_opt>'],
                  ('<test>', 'LP'): ['<sum>', '<test_opt>'],
                  ('<test_opt>', 'COMPARE'): 
['COMPARE', '<sum>'], ('<test_opt>', 'RP'): ['E'],
                  ('<test_opt>', 'SC'): ['E'],
                  ('<test_opt>', 'WHILE'): ['E'], 
('<sum>', 'num'): ['<term>', '<sum_opt>'],
                  ('<sum>', 'id'): ['<term>', '<sum_opt>'],
                  ('<sum>', 'LP'): ['<term>', '<sum_opt>'],
                  ('<sum_opt>', 'SUB'): ['SUB', '<term>', '<sum_opt>'],
                  ('<sum_opt>', 'ADD'): ['ADD', '<term>', '<sum_opt>'],
                  ('<sum_opt>', 'COMPARE'): ['E'], ('<sum_opt>', 'RP'): ['E'],
                  ('<sum_opt>', 'WHILE'): ['E'],
                  ('<sum_opt>', 'SC'): ['E'], 
('<term>', 'num'): ['num'], ('<term>', 'id'): ['id'],
                  ('<term>', 'LP'): ['<paren_expr>']}

    myStack.append('$')  # push starting 
                         # elements on to the stack
    myStack.append('<program>')


    def get_next_token():  # get next token 
                           # from scanner output
        global count
        if len(output) != 0:  # scanner output
            next_token = output[count % (len(output))]
            count = count + 1
            return next_token


    token = get_next_token()  # Retrieve token from 
                              # scanner output
    x = myStack.pop()

    while x != '$':  # Check if output matches what is on the stack
        if x == 'E': # if production is epsilon,
                     # pop element off stack and 
                     # get new token from

            # scanner output
            myStack.pop()

        elif x in terminals:
            if x == token or x == '$':
                print(x)  # print to a file
                myStack.pop()
                token = get_next_token()

        else:  # if x is a non-terminal, 
               #check the parsing table

            key = (x, token)
            if key in parseTable:
                print(x)
                myStack.pop()
                production = parseTable.get(key)  # after 
                                                  #getting production, 
                                                  #push onto the stack

                for p in reversed(production):
                    myStack.append(p)  # pushing production 
                                       #rule on to the stack

            else:
                print("SYNTAX ERROR")  # print to a file ; 
                                       # end program once
                                       #syntax error found
                sys.exit()

        x = myStack[-1]

##output:

    x = myStack[-1] IndexError: list index out of range
    <program>
    <statement_list>
    <statement>
    id
    ASGN
    <expr>
    <test>
    <sum>
    <term>
    num
    <sum_opt>
    <test_opt>
    SC
    <statement_list>
    <statement>
    WHILE
    <paren_expr>
    LP
    <expr>
    <test>
    <sum>
    <term>
    id
    <sum_opt>
    <test_opt>
    COMPARE
    <sum>
    <term>
    num
    <sum_opt>
    RP
    <statement>
    id
    ASGN
    <expr>
    <test>
    <sum>
    <term>
    id
    <sum_opt>
    ADD
    <term>
    id
    <sum_opt>
    <test_opt>
    SC
    <statement_list>

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What output do you get from those print statements - edit this into the question.

Comment: @barny   i updated it with the output, thank you for any feedback given!

Comment: Your print statements would be some use if they identified which line is printing. And do you get an execption as the first output? How? And am I missing something: where’s the “SYNTAX ERROR” output?